# Cat Is On/Up A Tree

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, usage

I have a question about the choosing between the prepositions "*on*" and "*up*" in this situation.  Let's say a cat climbed a tree and is sitting on a branch.

1. The cat is ***on*** the tree.
2. The cat is ***up*** the tree.

Is either "*on*" or "*up*" not as good as the other?

Comment: _The cat is up on/in the tree_. Or _The cat is on/in the tree_. _The cat is up a tree_ means it's a drunk cat or the cat is in trouble .

Comment: [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6395/is-it-correct-to-say-the-bird-is-in-the-tree-or-on-the-tree) is a similar post.

Answer (score 2):

When you remark that X is on Y, it usually implies A) X is stably placed and isn't having to perform extra effort to stay on Y, and/or B) X is at the topmost or outermost *flat surface* of Y.

Trees are not flat at the top, and a cat cannot lay without great effort on the outer/top surface of a tree, so *on* should not be used.

A cat can be on a *branch* of the tree, or *on the tree branch*.  Something like a [net of lights](http://www.festive-lights.com/templates/festive-lights.com.new/_images/content/inspiration/christmas-lights/outdoorchristmas6.jpg) could be *on* a tree, but not a cat.  Unless the cat is really stretchy.

Or, unless the cat is doing [this](https://www.denverlibrary.org/files/cat%20in%20tree.jpg) - if you said "There's a cat on the tree," and the cat was in this specific spot (which can also be considered the "top" of the tree), it would work.

Notice above *on* can apply if X is at the topmost or outermost flat surface of Y.  Trees do have such a surface on the trunk.  [These kittens](http://catnipsum.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/cat-climb-tree.jpg) could be considered to be *on* the tree.  Branches don't really have flat surfaces though.

*Up* works if you are at the base of the tree and the cat is on a branch above you.

Since trees have an interior consisting of branches and such that may accomodate a cat, a cat may also be *in* the tree as well.

Comment: 'Lie' not 'lay'

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say a cat climbed a tree and is sitting on a branch.

The branch is only a small part of the tree, so I would say #1, "*on* the tree," would be less exact, as it implies "on the [entire] tree."

Option 2 is commonly used and would be fine.

A third option: The cat is *in* the tree.

Comment: Are you sure about the validity of the sentence *"The cat is in the tree"*?

Comment: @VarunKN Yes.  If the branch is in the tree, and the cat is on the branch, then the cat is in the tree.  (Granted, I am assuming a full, deciduous tree with lush foliage, not a Charlie Brown tree. ;))

Comment: @Varun - Absolutely. Not only is "in the tree" valid, it's idiomatic and relatively common. _"Upon entering the outer fringes of Wonderland, Alice found a Cheshire Cat perched high in a tree"_ (Alan Bisbort). I would probably use _in_ or _up in_ here. In this context, _in_ doesn't mean "inside of", it means "in amongst the branches of".